# Sort data by createDate

Tags: spring

I have a set of data that I return in a method, how can I sort this data by createDate, I can do it using a stream, but the method returns a list, so I don’t want to use a stream, but if I can use a stream and return data in view list, can you show how?

```
  public List<Mark> getMarksByUser(){
    List<Mark> marks = markService.getMarksByUser(AuthenticationController.selfUserName());
}
```

sorting should be in this method

my mark entity with createDate

```
public class Mark extends BaseEntity<Integer> {
private String mark;
private String text;
private String sku;
private Date dateCreated;
private Date dateUpdated;
private Boolean deleted;
private String username;
```

Comment: you use a comparator? show us what you tried with the Stream api

Comment: `marks.sort(Comparator.comparing(Mark::getDateCreated))`

Comment: Can you write your answer as a separate one so that I can mark it out as correct?